# QFtp create directory only if it doesn't exist

Tags: c++, qt, ftp

I inherited a project at work and at a certain point I'm supposed to send (recursively) a folder and its content to a ftp server using QFtp (connected with signals and slots).

This works perfectly okay except that if I try to create a destination directory :

```
m_pFtp->mkdir(sRemoteFullPath);
```

and that directory already exist, all subsequent commands won't execute (all the put() and other mkdir() for deeper folders that already have been 'started').
I do catch the error but all other commands are discarded and not carried out (if I debug-jump the mkdir() when I know the folder exists, everything works fine).

So my question is, is there a way to :

A) Ignore this 'error' ("Creating directory failed: Directory already exixts")?

or

B) Somehow only create the directory if it doesn't exist?

I know that I can do it 'the long way', ie. scanning the whole subfolder structure on the server and act accordingly but a simpler solution would be both faster (to code) and in my opinion neater :-)

Thanks!

ps. I'm using WinXP, Qt and Filezilla server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some looking, it seems the "[Long Way](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/47446-How-to-check-the-file-to-download-from-ftp-site-exists)" is in fact the way everyone recommends.